# write iterative function to calculate a mathematics sequence

Tags: c, algorithm, pseudocode

for a homework, I need to program two functions to calculate a same mathematics sequence, recursive and iterative version. I succeeded to program the recursive version, but **I don't know how to realize the iterative version.**

(It's the first time I program with C language.)

the recursive version :

```
float sequence(int n)
{
    float x = 1.0;
    
    if(n>=1)
    {
        float temp = sequence(n-1);
        x = temp+1/temp;
    }
    return x;
}
```

if the code works efficiently, I must to find sequence(0) = 1, sequence(1) = 2, sequence(3) = 2.5, sequence(4) = 2.9,..., sequence(100) ~ 14.284066.

Also, according to my professor, it's necessary the code is enough optimized (time complexity?) and without obvious semantic problems (too easy to discover).

**Could you help me to realize iterative version with any suggestions?**

So, if this question has already been asked, I'm sorry, could you give me the link please.

else I thank you for your time,

Sincerely.

Comment: If this is the very first time you're writing C then you should definitely take many steps back, and find some books or classes to learn the basics of C first. If this really is the very first homework assignment for the very first time to write C, then your teacher is wanting you to run when you just have been born, it's not going to work.

Comment: mathematics sequence?  What mathematics sequence?

Comment: This is a sequence : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence

Comment: Write a loop over `n`, where each iteration computes the result for `n` given the previous value you calculated for `n-1`. Similar to what you have but using a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: This looks like the sequence which leads to the Golden Ratio, which is about 1.6 and not 14.28..., as you mention. Are you sure your prorgram is correct?

Comment: @Dominique I'm not perfectly sure, but the first  four values are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I made it out, apparently it's the [Fractional Chromatic Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalChromaticNumber.html) sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double seqrec(unsigned n) {
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    double prev = seqrec(n - 1);
    return prev + 1 / prev;
}

double seqiter(unsigned n) {
    double numerator = 1, denominator = 1;
    for (unsigned k = 2; k <= n; k++) {
        double newnumerator = numerator*numerator + denominator*denominator;
        denominator = numerator*denominator;
        numerator = newnumerator;
        // avoid nan, get numbers down to a reasonable level :-)
        while (denominator > 2) {
            numerator /= 2;
            denominator /= 2;
        }
    }
    return numerator / denominator;
}

int main(void) {
    for (int k = 1; k < 49; k++) {
        printf("%d ==> %f, %f\n", k, seqrec(k), seqiter(k));
    }
}
```

With the following output

```
1 ==> 1.000000, 1.000000
2 ==> 2.000000, 2.000000
3 ==> 2.500000, 2.500000
4 ==> 2.900000, 2.900000
5 ==> 3.244828, 3.244828
6 ==> 3.553010, 3.553010
7 ==> 3.834462, 3.834462
8 ==> 4.095255, 4.095255
9 ==> 4.339440, 4.339440
10 ==> 4.569884, 4.569884
11 ==> 4.788708, 4.788708
12 ==> 4.997533, 4.997533
13 ==> 5.197631, 5.197631
14 ==> 5.390027, 5.390027
15 ==> 5.575555, 5.575555
16 ==> 5.754909, 5.754909
17 ==> 5.928674, 5.928674
18 ==> 6.097345, 6.097345
19 ==> 6.261351, 6.261351
20 ==> 6.421061, 6.421061
21 ==> 6.576799, 6.576799
22 ==> 6.728848, 6.728848
23 ==> 6.877462, 6.877462
24 ==> 7.022865, 7.022865
25 ==> 7.165257, 7.165257
26 ==> 7.304819, 7.304819
27 ==> 7.441715, 7.441715
28 ==> 7.576093, 7.576093
29 ==> 7.708087, 7.708087
30 ==> 7.837821, 7.837821
31 ==> 7.965407, 7.965407
32 ==> 8.090950, 8.090950
33 ==> 8.214545, 8.214545
34 ==> 8.336280, 8.336280
35 ==> 8.456238, 8.456238
36 ==> 8.574494, 8.574494
37 ==> 8.691119, 8.691119
38 ==> 8.806179, 8.806179
39 ==> 8.919735, 8.919735
40 ==> 9.031846, 9.031846
41 ==> 9.142565, 9.142565
42 ==> 9.251944, 9.251944
43 ==> 9.360029, 9.360029
44 ==> 9.466867, 9.466867
45 ==> 9.572498, 9.572498
46 ==> 9.676964, 9.676964
47 ==> 9.780302, 9.780302
48 ==> 9.882549, 9.882549
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it's extremely helpful for my work. Sincerely!

Comment: You shouldn't be invoking the recursion twice, that leads to exponential run times.  Also, having `nan` as an outcome is indicative of a bug.

Comment: I got rid of the `nan` result and the double recursive call. `nan` was because the `numerator` and `denominator` are growing exponentially fast.

Comment: @mxbr236 Please consider accepting the answer if it helped/solved your problem

Comment: I'm left wondering why you need the `numerator`/`denominator` at all, the basic recurrence relationship is pretty simple.

Comment: @pjs: that's from trying to convert the recursive function to iterative on paper. I ended up with `a/b + b/a` and somehow didn't think to convert all of it to `double`. After publishing (and realizing the possible simplification) I just left it for the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion works deconstructively, starting with `n` and working backwards with recursive calls until it gets to the base case. For the base case, it returns the known answer, and at each level above the base case it evaluates the equation using returned result.

For iteration, you want to work constructively from the base case up to `n`. At each iteration, the current value is used to update the result from the previous iteration.

You used the `pseudocode` tag, so I'm providing this in Ruby (which is practically pseudocode but can be run to check the answers). You can translate it to C for yourself to enforce your understanding.

```ruby
def recursive(n)
  return 1.0 if n < 2
  x = recursive(n - 1)
  return x + 1 / x
end

def iterative(n)
  x = 1.0
  if n > 1
    (n - 1).times { x += 1.0 / x }
  end
  return x
end

# Test it out
(0..10000).each { |input| puts "#{recursive(input)}\t#{iterative(input)}"}
```

I've tested, and both of those return identical answers for `n` up to 10000.

Comment: Perfect, I'm going to consult that!

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be too quick to check off something as "the" answer around here, good alternative answers can drift in for hours afterwards.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, it works!

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be too quick to check off something as "the" answer around here, good alternative answers can drift in for hours afterwards. I dont use this site often.

Comment: Glad that works for you.  Notice that it also reduces the number of variables being declared (relative to your initial implementation).

Comment: As for not using the site often, certainly no problem.  My comment was meant as general guidance and applies equally to my own answer.  Welcome aboard the SS Stackoverflow, enjoy the voyage.

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that you can upvote all answers that you found helpful, regardless of which one you select as "the" answer.  You upvote an answer by clicking the upward-pointing triangle next to it. You should take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site if you haven't done so already.